# Set Initial version of a Sharepoint Doclib Item

Tags: c#, sharepoint, versioning, document-library

I've got the following problem:
I am creating a file during runtime. This file gets pushed to a document library. This works perfectly! But...I would like to set the version of this file. It gets set to version 1.0 but I would like to have it in 0.1 first.

How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document library must be configured to **create major and minor versions** to get version numbers like `0.1` or `2.7`.

More information:

- [Major and minor versioning from a user’s perspective](http://henkhooiveld.com/2010/01/18/major-and-minor-versioning-from-a-users-perspective/)
- [Versioning, content approval, and check-out planning](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262378.aspx)